# Bings Search API always returns the same 10 results

Tags: c#, bing-api

I am trying to figure Bings Seach API out. I have added the SOAP service to my solution, and I do receive results. The issue, is that the displayed results are always the same, not matter what I have set the `request.Web` to. When I do the search, it displays 98 results, so it isn't the lack of results.

```
        BingService soapClient = new BingService();

        string resp = string.Empty;
        SearchRequest request = new SearchRequest();
        request.AppId = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["BingKey"];
        request.Sources = new BingLiveSearchService.SourceType[] { SourceType.Web };
        request.Query = query;
        request.Web = new BingLiveSearchService.WebRequest { Count = 10, Offset = 10 };

        var response = soapClient.Search(request);
        if (response.Web != null && response.Web.Total > 0)
        {
            resp += "TOTAL COUNT:"+response.Web.Total +"<br/><br />";
            foreach (var item in response.Web.Results)
            {
                resp += "<div style='padding-bottom:10px;'>" + item.Title + "</div>";
            }

        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this is weird with these API but you need to set specified variable to true so add

```
request.Web.CountSpecified = true;
request.Web.OffsetSpecified = true;
```

Comment: If I specify the value, why also state I have specified it, wierd :) One wierd thing is that if I do the initial search without the offset it says 98 results, if I then set the offset to 10, it says there are 18 results. Do you know why this happens?

Comment: its bing my friend, its bing :)

Comment: I am having the same issue I am getting only 41 results for a simple word 'game'  I am using json..  Please help me to fix this issue.  I have asked a question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8637051/bing-api-returns-41-results-for-simple-word-game

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at [WebRequest.Count](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd251004.aspx). It looks like you can configure the number of results to return via this.

EDIT:
[Here's](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/BingSearch.aspx#heading0008) an example where `.Count` is used.