# Bing Api returns 41 results for simple word "Game"

Tags: search, web, bing

I am trying to implement bing search in my site.  I need search result in JSON format.

This is the URL I am using

http://api.search.live.net/json.aspx?AppId=(MYAPPID)&Query=game&Version=2.2&Sources=web&web.Count=50&Web.CountSpecified%20=%20True&web.Offset=1&Web.OffsetSpecified%20=%20true&Web.FileType=html

I am trying to search a simple word game I should get millions of results but I am getting a total of 41 Following is the part of my result..

```
{"SearchResponse":{"Version":"2.2","Query":{"SearchTerms":"game"},"Web":  
 {"Total":41,"Offset":1,"Results":
```

I dont know where I am going wrong..  Please help me..  I read some ware that It is not possible to get more than 1000 results.  For now even 1000 results is enough for me..

Please help..

Comment: Please remove your AppID from your question, otherwise other people might abuse it. Since it has now been compromised, you might want to generate a new one at the Bing Administration.

Comment: Thank you  Dofs..  I removed my AppID.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally I got answer I put &market=en-US in the URL and I got more results..   I hope this will help some one..

Comment: I tried it when doing a search like "site:mysite.com" but unfortunately it didn't return more results, so it might just be for regular queries.

Comment: Yes it is not working for all queries.  I tried with following example if I give the query wild+game I get 65000000 results by putting "&market=en-US" with out "&market=en-US" I am getting 41 results.

Comment: Okay, but it doesn't work with "site:{mysite.com}", but that might because it isn't a 'traditional' query.